# Plotly - add reversed bar plot to existing normal one

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

Here's a code:

```
import plotly
import plotly.express as px

x = data
fig = px.line(x=fruits, y=[1,3,2], color=px.Constant("Line"),
             labels=dict(x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="Line"))
fig.add_bar(x=fruits, y=[1,3,1], name="Red")
fig.add_bar(x=fruits, y=[2,1,3], name="Green").update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.show()
```

I want to change it, so one bar plot would've been placed normally, and the other would be drawn right opposite the first one, hanging upside down. How can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you assuming a stacked graph? Is it possible to change the y-value of a bar chart that is reversed in the current code to a negative value? `y=[-2,-1,-3]`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a secondary y-axis and reverse the range of values, mapping the first group of bars to the default y-axis, and the second group of bars to the secondary y-axis. Then to make sure the bars don't overlap, you can insert empty data for each group of bars. Also you didn't specify your `fruits` variable, so I created an arbitrary list for you. Feel free to modify my code to suit your purposes!

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# x = data
fruits = ["apple","pear","orange"]
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
# fig = px.line(x=fruits, y=[1,3,2], color=px.Constant("Line"),
#              labels=dict(x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="Line"))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=fruits, 
        y=[1,3,1], 
        marker_color="Tomato",
        name="Red"
    )
)

# empty plot
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=fruits, 
        y=[0,0,0], 
        name=None,
        showlegend=False
    )
)

# empty values
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=fruits, 
        y=[0,0,0], 
        name=None,
        showlegend=False
    ),
    secondary_y=True
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=fruits, 
        y=[2,1,3], 
        marker_color="LightGreen",
        name="Green",
    ),
    secondary_y=True
)
fig['layout']['yaxis2']['autorange'] = "reversed"
fig.show()
```

[image]